# Spyder Permission Error while starting the Kernel, Administrator rights do not change anything

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

when I start Spyder I get an error that says permission denied. This is the output from that in Spyder:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1223, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 313, in start_kernel
self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 220, in _launch_kernel
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 131, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

It eventual pops up with a prompt that says

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZA2l.png)

The advice I've found is to run Spyder in with administrator rights, but this does not fix my issue. I've found some other advice to do the following

As per @CarlosCordoba: "To fix this the OP needs to run conda update anaconda and then conda update jupyter_client in the Anaconda Prompt"

When I run conda update anaconda in the Anaconda cmd prompt with administrator rights this is what happens

```
    Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 58, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='system')
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\John\\anaconda3\\Menu\\notebook.json'menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 58, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='system')
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\John\\anaconda3\\Menu\\notebook.jsodone
Rolling back transaction: - menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 58, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='system')
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\John\\anaconda3\\Menu\\notebook.json'menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 58, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='system')
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\John\\anaconda3\\Menu\\notebook.jsodone

[WinError 5] Access is denied
()
```

Any help? I've only got a little knowledge in Python, and using this for mathematical optimization in a class.

EDIT: A little extra information. When I try to launch Spyder from the Anaconda Navigator it just spins forever, never launching.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! I did a soft boot, and then in the Anaconda terminal ran `spyder --reset`. Then, ran Spyder with Administrative privileges, and it was able to connect!